# calculate number of ways to get a number k with the xor of p elements

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor

You are given 3 numbers k,p,n.
What are the number of ways of choosing p unique elements from 1 to 2^n - 1 such that the xor of all the p elements is equal to k?
0 <= k <= 2^n - 1
0<=p<=n

Answer (score 0):

The XOR suite for n=3 is 9, right ? So k may be bigger than n. But p may be equal to 3.
The first question of your problem is “what is the biggest value of p for any value of n” isn't it ?